# Flask: Don't redirect to Url

Tags: python, flask

I'm starting with Flask and have this problem. I need make a redirect to url. When I try with this code, work good:

```
@app.route('/fa')
def hello():
    return redirect(url_for('foo'))

@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    return 'Hello Foo!'
```

But now, I need this same but with a render template. This is the code, but then I but the user, flask redirect and give this error: Method Not Allowed

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from forms import MyForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
  return render_template('about.html')

@app.route("/signin", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def signin():
  form = MyForm()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == True:
      return redirect(url_for('foo'))
  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template("signin.html", form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.debug = True
  app.run()
```

signin.html

```
{% block content %}
  <h2>Sign In</h2>

  <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('signin') }}">

  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

  {{ form.username.label }}
  {{ form.username(size=20) }}

  {{ form.password.label }}
  {{ form.password(size=20) }}

  {{ form.submit }}
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

MyForm.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form, TextField, PasswordField, DataRequired, SubmitField

class MyForm(Form):
  username = TextField("Username", validators=[DataRequired()])
  password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired()])
  submit = SubmitField("Sign In")

def validate(self):    
    user = "franco"
    if user == self.username:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Error:

```
 ValueError
 ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Why?? Thanks

Comment: Why what? — Please clarify the question and tell us what exactly does not work.

Comment: your indentation is very inconsistent.  if this is your literal code you probably have a syntax error, because you have a `return` at top level

Comment: Sorry, was my error, I wrote bad the code here. I edit my post

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `signin.html`?

Comment: You have a bug: "username" == "franco" is always False.

Comment: Yes. I change the code, but continuous don't working....

Comment: Please provide reproducible example. Right now indentation is wrong, wtf imports won't work with current version of flask-wtf, it is not clear what is the content of each file, Myform should be (judging from imports) in forms.py not MyForm.py, not to mention missing config and exact error message.

Comment: @zero323 I edit and put the error, and corrected indentation problem, but I don't undertan what config file missing

Comment: @F.N.B You need at lest some dummy `SECRET_KEY` in app config to make it work otherwise csrf will fail. I doesn’t have to be separate in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not with redirection (it works fine) but with the case when http method is POST and form was invalid. In this situation there is no valid response from `signin` function hence the error.

```
@app.route("/signin", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def signin():
    form = MyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == True:
            return redirect(url_for('foo'))
        else:
            # If method is POST and form failed to validate
            # Do something (flash message?)
            return render_template("signin.html", form=form)

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("signin.html", form=form)
```